# Not visible polish characters in game / AST.dll

Tags: c++

Gothic II Returning 2.0  / Visual Studio 2015

I'm trying to translate from Russia to Polish few lines of an AST.dll file. I have visual studio 2015, and project of it. I found lines with russian Text and I translated this into polish, with polish characters like L with line `Ł` but in game they look like strange symbols.

I tried to save this part of the script (with lines I translated) ConstText.cpp using encoding with UNICODE (UTF-8), and replace this with original script it changed a Little cause I got diffrent types of symbols, but this still isn't polish characters.

> 1>ConstText.cpp(95): warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u00F3' cannot be represented in the current code page (1251)

In my opinion i should Save this ConstText.cpp with specific encoding but i don't know what Type of encoding.

Comment: The warning complains to 1251 code page, which is cyrillic one. Try to do a full text search for 1251 string to find a place where the code page is being set, then replace it with correct code page (and might be save the file as ANSI in that code page)

Comment: I saved ConstText.cpp as encoding (UTF-8 without signature) and it helped a little cause now i don't have error on Visual Studio while building. But in game it's still not working and i Have another strange symbols.